For every object, is there a unique notion of isomorphism?
Do you think that, according to most mathematicians, the following claim holds?
(Claim) For every object, there is a unique notion of isomorphism.
Perhaps one might think that for some sets, such as $(\{0,+\})$ (i.e. the zero group with singleton $\{0\}$ and $0 + 0 = 0$), there is an ambiguity in the term "isomorphism". By "isomorphism" we might mean bijection or we might mean bijective homomorphism.
To give another example: $S=\{R,\cdot$$,+,1,0\}$ is, say, a field.  Yet it is also (by definition) a ring. In general, isomorphism among fields and rings is bijective homomorphism. Would most mathematicians say that there is a difference between field isomorphism and ring isomorphism, and hence ambiguity in the term "isomorphism for $S$"?
Many thanks in advance!

The claim is simply wrong or at least misleading or based on a misunderstanding, and this is not a matter of polling mathematicians.

This is a rigid conception, and my advice would be to discard it as fast as possible. You might enjoy reading McLarty, C. (2007). The Last Mathematician from Hilbert’s Gottingen: Saunders Mac Lane as Philosopher of Mathematics. The British Journal for the Philosophy of Science, 58(1), 77–112. doi:10.1093/bjps/axl030

An isomorphism, as discussed in full mathematical generality, is an "invertible homomorphism," where the meaning of "homomorphism" depends on the object and setting (by which I mostly mean category) in question.
If you take this point of view, there is no ambiguity in the term "isomorphism" whatsoever; at most there is as to setting.
As I noted in a comment on an answer to your last question, you pick your examples poorly: $\mathrm{Field}$ is a full subcategory of $\mathrm{Ring}$; in particular, an isomorphism two fields as rings is the same as an isomorphism of them as fields, so you might as well ask whether a bijection in $\mathrm{FinSet}$, the category of finite sets, is the same as a bijection in $\mathrm{Set}$, which I'd wager you'd be hard-pressed to find anybody willing to affirm.
Generally, I think questions pertaining to object identity alone are misplaced: There is no "naked" $\mathbb{Z}$, only the set $\mathbb{Z}$, the ring $\mathbb{Z}$, the abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$, the multiplicative monoid $\mathbb{Z}$, the discrete topological group $\mathbb{Z}$, ..., all of which come with potentially differing notions of homomorphisms, isomorphisms, etc. with varying degrees of relatedness (from totally disparate to complete identification as in the example above) which we in turn study (the language of category theory and functors is one way to give rigorous footing to this).

@andpersand A set is something completely amorphous: On a set you can force anything that fits its size (cardinality), so this is already not true: Your sets have some structure (as in your question, say, a ring structure), and at that point its fate is already determined, it becomes a ring and is no longer a "pure" set. To then ask about different notions of isomorphism is to change the object; at the very least its interpretation as "ring" or "group" or whatever :)

Can it happen that a given structure defines an object in several (non-nested) categories? Yes, although I don't have a good example from the top of my head, but really I'd like to get you away from this conception: It's not really how we conceptualize things. Moreover, not every category is concrete: that is to say, the objects of a category need to be of the form set + structure. Also, it happens that we identify objects as at least "morally" the same even though they are not backed by isomorphic data or live in the same or even formally closely related categories.

Again I don't have any great examples. The closest that comes to mind is something like the category of spectra (in stable homotopy theory, in algebraic topology) where people started out with an "on the nose"-definition of what a spectrum should be and how the category should look like and then found out that the direct approach doesn't work out so great. Cue decades of constructing different models, different categories as an approximation to a "good" category of spectra, all different, often diverging from each other.
